How to call a function in method using Pinia in Vue3
I am getting the following error when trying to set a Token using pinia in vue 3.
error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setToken')
The following is my code set up:
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'

export default {
    setup() {
        const userStore = useUserStore()

        return {
            userStore
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            },
            errors: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async submitForm() {
            this.errors = []

            if (this.form.email === '') {
                this.errors.push('Wrong email')
            }

            if (this.form.password === '') {
                this.errors.push('Wrong Password')
            }

            if (this.errors.length === 0) {
                await axios
                    .post('/api/login/', this.form)
                    .then(response => {
                        // Save the token to local storage
                        this.userStore.setToken(response.data.access)

                        console.log(response.data.access)

                        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + response.data.access;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('error', error)
                    })
                
                await axios
                    .get('/api/auth/')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.userStore.setUserInfo(response.data)

                        this.$router.push('/dashboard-banking')
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('error', error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

The user.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user",{

    state: () => ({
        user: {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            id: null,
            name: null,
            email: null,
            organization: null,
            role: [],
            access: null,
            refresh: null,
        }
    }),

    actions: {
        initStore() {
            console.log('initStore', localStorage.getItem('user.access'))

            if (localStorage.getItem('user.access')) {
                console.log('User has access!')

                this.user.access = localStorage.getItem('user.access')
                this.user.refresh = localStorage.getItem('user.refresh')
                this.user.id = localStorage.getItem('user.id')
                this.user.name = localStorage.getItem('user.name')
                this.user.email = localStorage.getItem('user.email')
                this.user.isAuthenticated = true

                this.refreshToken()

                console.log('Initialized user:', this.user)
            }
        },

        setToken(data) {
            console.log('setToken', data)

            this.user.access = data.access
            this.user.refresh = data.refresh
            this.user.isAuthenticated = true

            localStorage.setItem('user.access', data.access)
            localStorage.setItem('user.refresh', data.refresh)

            console.log('user.access: ', localStorage.getItem('user.access'))
        },

        removeToken() {
            console.log('removeToken')

            this.user.refresh = null
            this.user.access = null
            this.user.isAuthenticated = false
            this.user.id = false
            this.user.name = false
            this.user.email = false

            localStorage.setItem('user.access', '')
            localStorage.setItem('user.refresh', '')
            localStorage.setItem('user.id', '')
            localStorage.setItem('user.name', '')
            localStorage.setItem('user.email', '')
        },

        setUserInfo(user) {
            console.log('setUserInfo', user)

            this.user.id = user.id
            this.user.name = user.name
            this.user.email = user.email

            localStorage.setItem('user.id', this.user.id)
            localStorage.setItem('user.name', this.user.name)
            localStorage.setItem('user.email', this.user.email)

            console.log('User', this.user)
        },

        testCall(){
            console.log('Testing Calling from')
        },

        refreshToken() {
            axios.post('/api/refresh/', {
                refresh: this.user.refresh
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.user.access = response.data.access

                    localStorage.setItem('user.access', response.data.access)

                    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + response.data.access
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error)

                    this.removeToken()
                })
        },
    }
})

I am learning Vue3 and am unable to figure out what is wrong. Please help or guide me to solving this issue.
Thanks in Advance
The setToken function should initialize and store the tokens but it is not being read.

I have to see your userStore code

I have added the user.js.

Are you sure that's how you define store ? I think it should be defineStore("user", {})

as @cantdocpp says, you're missing the first arguement. i've done the same in transitioning v2 to v3
export const useUserStore = defineStore("user",{

Thank you @cantdocpp and Marker. After reading your comments, went through the entire documentation of pinia to check if there was anything I was missing.
I have added modified the code as suggested but the error still persists.. I can't seem to access the instance of userStore from the methods

you can try to console.log(this.userStore) on form submit to see what it gets you. From what is see, your this.userStore is undefined

You are right. It is showing as "undefined". Any ideas as to why or some resource you could refer me to.

@cantdocpp Thank you. I realised that there was another script that was causing the issue.
It got resolved.

Refer to documentation of Composing Stores Pinia.
Here they describe that you can use other stores inside actions and getters `, however they describe no way of attaching the one store as a property of another store like you do in your example.
As per documentation: Composing Stores Pinia: Shared Actions, my suggestion would be to call the const userStore = useUserStore() in the action where it's needed.
